# Is it possible to convert a hair particle system to a mesh and bake the particle color to the new mesh UV?

Tags: uv, particles, texture-painting, hair

I am aware that hair particles can be converted to a mesh, that's pretty straightforward. I'm wondering how to take a hair particle system that has color driven by the emitter's UV texture and convert that system to a mesh that already has UV's and can bake out a texture to those UV's based on the original visual texture of the particle system.

Once you bake the hair to a mesh it is no longer paired to the emitter and you lose all reference to the hair particle location to drive its color, so this UV texture baking would need to be done in a single step, I'm just not aware of such a feature and I'm having a hard time searching for it because I'm getting drowned in results about basic hair particle color shaders.